# Changing QML properties with compile-time safety from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Is it possible to invoke functions or change properties in a QML component from C++ with compile-time safety?

The current suggestions to change a property is to use any of the following functions:

```
QQmlProperty::write(object, "someNumber", 100);
QMetaProperty::write(object, "someNumber", 100) 
object->setProperty("someNumber", 100);
```

where object is a `QObject *` to the QML component which has a property called `someNumber`. Refer to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html for more information.

Currently I can change `"someNumber"` to say `"otherNumber"` without any compilation errors, even if there is no property called `otherNumber`.

It's even possible to change the number `100` to another type such as `"100"` (string literal) without any compilation errors, i.e. no type checking. Similar problem will occur when you try to invoke a function defined in the QML component from C++.

I'm aware that each function will return false if they fail to convert the type or if the property doesn't exist but I'm looking for a compile-time error check.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: You would need an extra tool for this, and AFAIK one does not exist. It can't be part of "normal" building, because QML files can be loaded from disk at runtime, and in that case there's nothing preventing them being changed after compilation. But of course there *could* be a tool, which checks the C++ code against current QML files, and complains about stuff like this...

Comment: @hyde QML files don't necessary need to be JIT as we are using Qt Quick Compiler and I thought it could be design in such a way that it's detected during the linker stage. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: I think QML component instances only use dynamic properties (ie. there is no specific C++ class  with non-dynamic properties, even if you use precompiled QML, at least AFAIK). QML compiler could certainly export a list of known properties, and then there could be a tool which checks C++ code against the list, but again, AFAIK nobody has written such a tool yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That entirely depends on the C++ type of `object`

If you have access to its declaration (header), you can cast to the concrete type and the call the setter methods directly instead of going through the abstracted property API.

However, setting QML object properties from C++ is usually not a good idea anyway, since you rely on the object to exist and be of a certain type.

Way better is to make the data available as properties on an object that you expose to QML and handle the assignment on the QML side.
The API of the exposed object is then full under C++ control and thus allows you always to call setters with respective type checking.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible since Qt Meta-Object System relies on QVariant, so all your data passed to it will be converted to QVariant first and back only on the receiver side. And whether the conversation is failed will be known only in the run-time.

But you can create a C++ class in which you will be modifying data from C++ and export it to QML.